# Is encryption at rest supported on remote protocol in OrientDB?

Tags: encryption, orientdb

In the documentation of OrientDB it mentioned that encryption at rest is not supported on remote protocol yet. It can be used only with plocal.

Currently we are using the OrientDB version 2.2.22. Database encryption is mandatory for us. We were previously using OrientDB in plocal mode, but now we have a new requirement in which multiple processes from different JVMs need to connect with same OrientDB database, which is not possible in plocal model.

Is there any way we can achieve it? Is there any workaround? Is this feature going to be supported in upcoming releases?

Comment: If my reply indeed answers your question, please upvote and accept it! (If not, comment on it as to why it doesn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your server and provide the key at startup, from that point on, the database is accessible via remote. So it would work. I suggest encrypting the TCP/IP connection too at that point.

Answer (score 1):

No, [it cannot currently be done](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Database-Encryption.html):

> NOTE: Encryption at rest is not supported on remote protocol yet. It can be used only with plocal.

Given your new requirements, it seems like OrientDB is not the right choice for you anymore.

Comment: It confirms my first part. But it doesn't answer if its going to be available in upcoming release. There are multiple issues filed on orientdb related to same feature. (https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/89, https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/issues/382). That's why wanted to know if its going to be fixed.

Comment: That question is best asked directly to the developers.